# Cross compile for dotnet45 and dnxcore50

Tags: .net, dnx, project.json

I am working on a library and I want to be able to compile it for the traditional .NET Framework, but also for .NET core. I started out with a classic VS solution that worked fine for .NET Framework 4.5. Then I added a `project.json` file that looked like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.3-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "net45": {
      "dependencies": {
      }
    },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.0.0-rc2-23811",
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Security.Principal": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.Hashing.Algorithms": "4.0.0-beta-23225",
        "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.Xml.XDocument": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now it compiles fine with .NET core, but VS 2015.1 complains that I am missing a *runtimes* section in my `project.json`. I added the following piece of code to the file:

```
"runtimes": {
  "win": {}
}
```

I tried to add it at the frameworks/net45 level, but this didn't help. It should be added at the root-level, but now it complains with the following error

**<*assembly*> provides a compile-time reference assembly for <*assembly*> on DNXCore,Version=v5.0, but there is no run-time assembly compatible with win.**

There is plenty of documentation about how to use the project.json file with dnxcore, but documentation about using project.json with the traditional .NET framework is scarce.  This is a pity, because it discourages developers to port their libraries to dnxcore, while maintaining compatibility with the traditional .NET framework which will be the most important framework for the next few years.